# Strict Bonferroni - looking for p value

Tags: regression, multiple-comparisons, bonferroni

I run 18 exploratory regressions and would like to know what the strict Bonferroni p-value would be. 
Nine regressions are negative binomial regressions with 4 predictor variables, the other 9 are WLS regressions with 6 predictor variables. These associations are yet unexplored (my dependent variables are clinical questionnaire items instead of clinical sum scores, we are looking for heterogeneity).

I am sure more information is needed, and would be glad if you could either help me directly (I will gladly provide all information that is necessary) or hint me at literature that enables a non-stats person to do the calculation himself.

I know that Bonferroni is very strict and do not plan to actually apply it to my analyses - I plan to use .01 as type I error to detect significant effects (and would appreciate feedback). My dependent variables are substantially correlated (between .3 and .6), but I at least want to provide what the p-value would be in the paper and discuss why it would be too conservative.

Comment: What do you mean by "strict Bonferroni"? It is known to be conservative when controlling for family-wise error rate, and your 3rd paragraph suggests you already know that. Is you question related to the fact that you used different models (NB vs. WLS regression) and have correlated outcomes?

Comment: I saw the term "strict Bonferroni" used several times in recent psychology papers, that's why I use it. My question is how you build the Bonferroni p-value. Do you just use 0.05 / 18 tests = .00278?

Comment: Maybe "strict" is in reference to Šidák correction or Holm-Bonferroni (which are different methods), or to account for all analytical steps (e.g., multiple tests with separate outcomes). I don't really know. Anyway, you're right that with usual Bonferroni correction you just have to adjust your $\alpha$ level by the number of tests. Another approach is to control False Discovery Rate.

Comment: A very well cited paper in my field runs 225 tests on alpha = .05 level, cite that a "strict Bonferroni correction" (Abdi, 2007) would be too conservative because of "substantial high correlations between a number of symptoms and between some of the validators". Abdi's book chapter is "Bonferroni and Sidak corrections for multiple comparisons". 

I have a problem with that, and want to do it better. Are there other options than simply stating "we use .01 to avoid false positives"?

Comment: Another approach I heard about is this: 
"In total, xx of the xxx analyses (xx%) were stat-
istically significant (p<0.05), far in excess of chance expectations (Feild & Armenakis, 1974)."

Answer (score 1):

If your analyses are at this stage exploratory then I strongly advise that you do not do any 'corrections' for multiple comparisons at all. They are mostly important where hypotheses are being tested within the Neyman-Pearson error-decision framework which implicitly precludes the re-testing of hypotheses. (That aspect of N-P hypothesis testing is usually not emphasised, but it is exactly what 'inductive behaviour' requires.) If you are at the exploratory stage then there is no reason at all to decrease the sensitivity of your analyses by 'correcting' via a Bonferroni or other method.

For hypothesis formation there is also no good reason to use a low cutoff for 'significance', which will lower the power of the tests. Instead, consider examining (and presenting, if appropriate) the actual P-values. The comparisons with the lowest P-values are the most convincing and should be focussed on in new experiments. (You cannot, of course, use the same data to form and test a hypothesis.)

You might find a recent paper of mine in the British Journal of Pharmacology helpful for understanding the differences between N-P hypothesis testing and the more commonly useful Fisherian 'significance testing'. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22394284

Another approach—probably better, but certainly more complex—is to use a multi-level Bayesian model that has the many comparisons built into it as model components. For many different types of problem such a model seems to do away with any reason to consider multiple comparison corrections.http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/multiple2f.pdf
This blog item might be relevant too: http://andrewgelman.com/2011/01/data_exploratio/ 
(I have to admit here that I do not completely understand the multi-level modelling, and I have never used it myself.)

Comment: Michael, what a wonderful and insightful paper, thank you. Immediately shared it with my colleagues. 
I read one of Gelman's books but it's a bit too complex for the message I'm trying to convey (hey, different predictors have differential effects on these items of that disorder that is supposedly this one distinct construct, maybe we shouldn't sum them up so easily into sum scores and only predict these by covariates).

Comment: Also, is this a sentence your paper would support?
"In order to provide as much information as possible about the probability of rejecting the null hypothesis that predictors do not affect symptoms, exact p-values will be displayed for all significant effects below p<.05 (Lew, 2012)."

Comment: @Torvon, Thanks for your enthusiasm about the paper:-)

Comment: @Torvon, I'm not sure that I completely understand 'information [] about the probability of rejecting the null hypothesis...'. It doesn't sound right to me. Perhaps you mean something like 'In order to show the strength of evidence within the data against the null hypothesis, exact P-values are displayed." The probability of rejecting the null hypothesis is something like the power of the experiment combined with a Bayesian prior, I suspect.